# Why do I get "storage decode error: input too short" error?

Tags: multiversx

So I have a rust contract that has a storage mapper for an arbitrary value. I store it based on a identifier which is an `u64`.

```
#[view(getVersion)]
#[storage_mapper("someValue")]
fn get_value(&self, identifier:u64) -> SingleValueMapper<u64>
```

When I query this using the API or erdJs I always get

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "code": "user error",
  "message": "storage decode error: input too short"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I was doing wrong here was not the code of the contract itself but rather I was calling a query for a value that was not stored.

I was trying to reach a value that was not set in my case. For example I had these values

```
1 -> 100
2 -> 200
3 -> 300
5 -> 500
```

notice how identifier "4" does not have any reference stored. So I was trying to query this view for the identifier "4" and therefore I was getting a `storage decode error` because the storage was empty for that value.